# Magento 2.3.5 : Display product count with Page Main Title

Tags: magento2, category

I want to display product count with page main title for category page.

How I can display that?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe this in details.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i added screenshot. i want to add count like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [**Observer**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html#observers) over Event `layout_generate_blocks_after`  you can show product count at title

Define an observer at `events.xml`

**events.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
        <observer instance="StackExchange\SampleModule\Observer\Frontend\Layout\GenerateBlocksAfter"
                  name="stackexchange_layout_generateblocksafter_layout_generate_blocks_after"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Observer Class:**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace StackExchange\SampleModule\Observer\Frontend\Layout;

class GenerateBlocksAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config
     */
    private $config;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $config
    ) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $fullActionName = $observer->getEvent()->getData('full_action_name');
        /**
         * @var $layout \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
         */
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getData('layout');
        if ($fullActionName === 'catalog_category_view') {
            $listBlock = $layout->getBlock('category.products.list');
            $categoryViewBlock = $layout->getBlock('category.products');
            $count  = 0;
            if ($listBlock) {
                /**
                 * @var $listBlock \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
                 */
                $productCollection = $listBlock->getLoadedProductCollection();
                if ($productCollection && $productCollection->count() >0) {
                    /**
                     * use this code when you want the same count as layer navigation
                     *
                     */
                    $count = $productCollection->count();
                }
            }

            if ($categoryViewBlock) {

                /**
                 * @var $categoryViewBlock \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
                 */
                $currentCategory = $categoryViewBlock->getCurrentCategory();
                if ($currentCategory) {
                    /**
                     * use this code when you want show count before applying filter
                     */
                    $count = $currentCategory->getProductCollection()->count();
                }
            }
            $title = $this->config->getTitle()->get();
            $this->config->getTitle()->set(
                $title
                . _(' Product Count: ' . (int) $count)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Use  `$count = $productCollection->count();` when want same result at Laynavigation .

And  use  `$count = $currentCategory->getProductCollection()->count();` when you always show category product count even applying filter.

**The folder structure of the module**

[image]

### Update

If you want to update `'page.main.title'` then use below code:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace StackExchange\SampleModule\Observer\Frontend\Layout;

class GenerateBlocksAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config
     */
    private $config;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $config
    ) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $fullActionName = $observer->getEvent()->getData('full_action_name');
        /**
         * @var $layout \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
         */
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getData('layout');
        if ($fullActionName === 'catalog_category_view') {
            $listBlock = $layout->getBlock('category.products.list');
            $categoryViewBlock = $layout->getBlock('category.products');
            $count  = 0;
            if ($listBlock) {
                /**
                 * @var $listBlock \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
                 */
                $productCollection = $listBlock->getLoadedProductCollection();
                if ($productCollection && $productCollection->count() >0) {
                    /**
                     * use this code when you want same count as layer navigation
                     *
                     */
                    $count = $productCollection->count();
                }
            }

            if ($categoryViewBlock) {

                /**
                 * @var $categoryViewBlock \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
                 */
                $currentCategory = $categoryViewBlock->getCurrentCategory();
                if ($currentCategory) {
                    /**
                     * use this code when you want show count before applying filter
                     */
                    $count = $currentCategory->getProductCollection()->count();
                }
            }

            /**
             * @var $pageMainTitle \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title
             */
            $pageMainTitle = $layout->getBlock('page.main.title');
            if ($pageMainTitle) {
                $oldTitle =$pageMainTitle->getPageTitle();
                $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle(
                    $oldTitle
                    . _(' Product Count: ' . (int) $count)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Actually it's page.main.title. How can i set?

Comment: Thanks..!! it's working.

Comment: Amit one more question. It's. not update when filter collection. what should i need to do?

Comment: Please read the comment on code and comment `$count = $currentCategory->getProductCollection()->count();`

Answer (score 0):

Let me share a basic idea for this task.

You can achieve this using the below code in your list page template file. Please use proper dependency instead of **objectmanager**

```
<?php        
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category'); echo $category->getProductCollection()->count();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me in which file should i need to add?

Comment: please check my updated question also.

Answer (score 0):

We can show the total number of product counts on the PLP page without using events. All we need to do is override the catalog_category_view.xml file and make the change accordingly. Below I'm posting the code which is worked for me.

> catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2018 Porto. All rights reserved.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="category.title"/>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="category.title" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-title">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products.count"
                       as="product_count" template="Magento_Catalog::product/category_title.phtml" />
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> category_title.phtml

```
<span class="category-product-count">
<?= '('.$this->getCurrentCategory()->getProductCollection()->count().' Results)'; ?>
```